# NSCalendar not returning the right date from components

Tags: nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

```
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setWeekOfYear:30];
[dateComponents setYear:2014];

NSDate *dayOfTheGivenWeek = [currentCalendar dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
```

`dayOftheGivenWeek` is actually `2014-01-01 00:00:00 CST`, despite me setting the `weekOfYear` to 30. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Did you try to add `weekday` component to 1?

Comment: Thanks Andriy ! That fixes it. Was the problem that the dateComponent couldn't pick a default date within the given weekOfYear so it juts defaulted to the first day of the year instead ?

Comment: `year` and `weekOfYear` isn't enough for `NSCalendar` to pick particular day. Data is to ambiguous. That's why you need third parameter.